# Retrieving images with Google images API and CURL gets always same link

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get a number of different images using Google's API and PHP. The code works fine for a single image, but when I try to get **different subject** images using the same code in a FOR - LOOP **I get always only the first result**:

```
$images = array("ironman poster", "superman returns poster", "the croods poster", "batman forever poster");

foreach ($images as $i) {
    $image = rawurlencode($i);
    $query = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=".$image."&imgsz=large&as_filetype=jpg";

    $json = get_url_contents($query);
    $data = json_decode($json);
    foreach ($data->responseData->results as $result) {
        $results[] = array("url" => $result->url, "alt" => $result->title);
    }

    echo $results[0]['url'];
    echo "<br />";
    echo $query;
    echo "<br />";
}

function get_url_contents($url) {
    $crl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

    $ret = curl_exec($crl);
    curl_close($crl);
    return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the `$results` array before the loop iterates. I'm not actually sure *why* it doesn't work, perhaps someone else can elaborate?

Working solution:

$images = array("ironman poster", "superman returns poster", "the croods poster", "batman forever poster");

```
foreach ($images as $i) {
    $image = rawurlencode($i);
    $query = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=".$image."&imgsz=large&as_filetype=jpg";

    $json = get_url_contents($query);
    $data = json_decode($json);
    $results = array(); //define array here!
    foreach ($data->responseData->results as $result) {
        $results[] = array("url" => $result->url, "alt" => $result->title);
    }

    echo $results[0]['url'];
    echo "<br />";
    echo $query;
    echo "<br />";
}
```